# How to update EU Blue Card to Permament Residency In Germany

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

I am about to complete my 33 months with my EU Blue-Card in Germany. I will be eligible for Permament Residency.

1. Where should I apply to update it? Should I have an appointment from Einwohnermeldeamt?
2. How long does it takes?
3. Should I apply earlier (Like in Ireland)
4. If I resign from my current position right after I complete my 33 months service, will my application still be processed?

Comment: Did you check any official website?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Ausländerbehörde
2. It depends
3. Yes
4. In order to apply for permanent residence permit, you should be able to fund yourself. If you will quit your job before applying, how do you fund yourself then? (First after you will get a permanent residence permit, you might become eligible for social help, etc.).

P.S. I'm not a lawyer.